# Passando parametros para procedure no postgresSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, procedure

Vou criar uma trigger no postgreSQL para copiar as informações de uma tabela para outra, as tabelas sempre terão a mesma estrutura, então eu pretendo passar os nomes da tabelas, fazer um **WHILE** e copiar os arquivos de uma para outra, só que não consigo lembrar como passar os parametros em texto (Nome das tabelas) para essa trigger, pois as que eu fiz até agora, não precisava passar parametros, apenas faziam algo em tabelas pré-definidas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copiartabela ()
RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$

-- Função (Aqui utilizarei o nome das tabelas)

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Se as tabelas tem a mesma estrutura e informação então por que 2 tabelas?

Comment: Pergunta pro meu professor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma função bem simples que copia dados de uma tabela para outra em PostgreSQL pode ser implementada da seguinte forma:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copiartabela(IN source VARCHAR, IN target VARCHAR) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'insert into ' || target || ' select * from ' || source;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

A função é declarada com os parâmetros `source` e `target`, respectivamente, o nome da tabela de origem e o nome da tabela de destino.

O termo `IN` antes dos parâmetros define que são ambos parêmetros de entrada, se fosse `OUT` seriam de saída. O tipo dos parâmetros é texto, representado pelo `VARCHAR`. O trecho `RETURNS VOID` define que a função não retorna um valor.

Dentro da função, o comando `EXECUTE` permite executar uma query dinâmica qualquer. Os valores passados para este comando são uma concateção de valores usando o operador `||` que montam uma inserção dinâmica.

A query gerada pela concatenação é um comando `INSERT`, que insere dados na tabela de destino a partir de um `SELECT` na tabela de origem.

**Veja um exemplo funcional da função no [**SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46239/1)**.**

#### Notas

- Cuidado para não confundir os termos **function** (função), **procedure** (procedimento) e **trigger** (gatilho). Função geralmente é uma rotina que retorna um valor; procedure é geralmente relacionada com uma rotina que executa vários comandos e pode ou não possuir parâmetros de saída; trigger é uma rotina executada quando ocorre alguma ação no banco de dados, por exemplo, um registro é inserido numa tabela.
- No PostgreSQL não há uma distrinção tão clara entre funções e procedimentos, pois uma `function` pode representar tanto uma quanto outra.

Comment: Eu posso não utilizar o `IN` ?

Comment: @LucasMotta Sim. Quando omitido, o modificador do parâmetro é o `IN` no final das contas.

Comment: Valeu, não conhecia essa do operador `||`